# Electron main process - unable to get user input on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, electron, command-line-interface, stdin

We are building a cross platform (OS) tool that requires both command line and graphical user interface.
We selected Electron as our solution and got stuck while trying to get input from the user in CLI mode.

It seems that electron's main process does not support stdin on Windows.
windows 10 with Electron 8.0.0

The basic example:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Question: ', (question) => {
    console.log(question)
    rl.close();
});
```

There are some discussions about it around the web but not none of them with a concrete answer.
Overcoming this problem will make the deployment / release process much easier for us so we are willing to consider workarounds / hacks as well :)

Using libraries like electron-prompt which uses a dialog to prompt the user are not an option as they break the look and feel of the CLI.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible using just electron on Windows. Best thing I can think of, is to detect if OS is Windows, then spawn a cmd process using stdin to capture user input and get it back to electron process using stdout.

Comment: Do you mean spawning a process from Electron's main process? Will it be possible to get input on the same terminal?

Comment: I think it's possible yes. If there are CLI arguments, then you spawn a CMD process on Windows only. I saw your comment about this issue [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4218#issuecomment-582925342). You can also try what [stelcheck](https://github.com/stelcheck) suggested [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4218#issuecomment-241316482) on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/stelcheck/a0c798ff31df5f2c0e5d72513948dcf1).

Comment: I actually called stelcheck regarding the issue :) as I am really into solving it. The thing is, if you want to spawn a child process you need to pass it stdin of the parent process (which in this case does not work). what stelcheck did is the other way around. He wrapped the electron process. (which won't help my case)